# Microsoft OData controller - invoking action on selection

Tags: c#, .net, odata, microsoft-odata

Is it possible to invoke an action while additionally querying OData resource?

I'd like to assign a list of resources to a person (selected in the query string) by using one OData POST query.

Ie. is it possible to perform something like this (in pseudo-query):

[Post]http://hostname.com/Resource/Assign?$filter=name eq 'resource name'

Answer (score 1):

I am using [LINQtoQueryString](http://linqtoquerystring.net/examples.html)

In the action method you get the value of the QueryString from the request, and you can use that library to filter a collection of items based on the query provided in the query string.